# My java.util.Scanner won't work

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

My code is getting this error:

```
Skriv din alder herunder og tryk enter:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Tasteturindtastning.main(Tasteturindtastning.java:20)
[Finished in 1.7s with exit code 1]
```

And my code is:

```
// Starter java som man plejer, læs i HejVerden.java

public class Tasteturindtastning
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        /* Jeg skal nu angive en variable, men jeg kan ikke bestemme denne variable
         * Da jeg ønsker at indtastningen fra dette tastetur skal være variablen.
         * I stedet for int og double bruger jeg så java.util.Scanner, som aflæser
         * brugerens indtastninger.
         */

        java.util.Scanner tastetur = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        // Printer en opgave/spørgsmål til brugeren

        System.out.println("Skriv din alder herunder og tryk enter:");

        int alder; // Angiver et variablenavn
        alder = tastetur.nextInt(); // Angiver variablen med værdien fra indtastningen

        /* Herunder gør jeg brug af et if statement der tjekker værdien for
         * variablen alder, og ser om den er lig med eller højere end 18, og hvis
         * dette er tilfældet, så udprinter den en sætning
         */

        if (alder >= 18) System.out.println("Du er myndig, da du er " + alder + " år gammel"); // Printes hvis han er 18 eller ældre

    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The swedish comments are very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)** is thrown by the scanner when there are no more elements to read from the scanner.you will have to check if any elements exists in the scanner before retrieving  the Integers using **[Scanner.hsNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)**

```
       while(tastetur.hasnextInt()){
        alder = tastetur.nextInt(); 
        }
```

Comment: Only trouble is, OP needs **exactly one int** so he may as well get an exception if he can't get the int.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i dont understand,if the next token in the scanner is not an valid int, hasNextInt() would simply return false.well, if he needs only one int. he could always break outta the loop after he find's one int ... :)

Comment: He should have a quite different `while` condition. Your loop breaks right away if the first token is not an int.

Comment: Something like `while (!tastetur.hasNextInt()) tastetur.nextToken(); alder = tastetur.nextInt();`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik do you mean `tasteur.next()` instead of nextToken ?? cuz scanner doesn't have nextToken method i believe. :)

Comment: Sure, whatever it's got. Didn't bother to check the Javadoc.